# SearchBar with slider in XPages

Tags: search, slider, xpages

I just want to add a search options my Main page. But It should be sliding when i click on it. otherwise the user should see only the open button of slider panel.

I found this and really nice interface but there is some issues of discussion tab on this project. 
https://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20Sliding%20Login%20Custom%20Control

https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Sliding%20Login%20Custom%20Control/discussions/8D26479636C73459862578E90029CF07

I will use it for commercial application. So I cannot user this component becase of the licensing issue.

any suggestion is important.
Regards,
C.A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm checking to see if it can be moved to Apache licensing. It's using a jQuery plugin with some Dojo modifications, because jQuery was not available in XPages at the time (4 years ago). From speaking to Declan (project chef) the animation is just a Dojo animation to move a div into view. Extension Library (which wasn't around when the custom control was written) does provide Dojo animations, so you could look at that. Alternatively, it may be worth looking at what jQuery plugins are available now to provide functionality you want, if you're developing on 9.0.1 with OpenNTF ExtLib.

Comment: did you have a time to check that This code can be move to Apache licensing?

Comment: Unfortunately it can't, because of the third-party project used was CC-SA - which is a very restrictive license that does not permit a change to other licenses - and insist that all modified versions remain under the same license - sort of like GPL.  The base code was then changed to GPL3 - which is why the OpenNTF project used GPL 3. As mentioned, the code just uses a Dojo animation to move a div so it's visible, which can be done with core functionality now in Extension Library.